# Error received when testing for element attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am trying to test for an attribute in a dynamic php photo gallery that loads images from a folder into a gallery.  The gallery uses lightbox to display the photo once clicked.  This is what I'm using to test:

```
if( $('#lightboxImage').attr('src') !== 'undefined'){ do something here }
```

I'm getting an initial error (Cannot call method 'attr' of null)  in debug I think because the #lightboxImage only has a 'src' attribute when an image from the gallery is clicked.  Nothing is obviously clicked when the page first loads.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: No, something is really wrong here.  $("#anything") should not return null under any circumstances, and attr() should always be defined on any jQuery object.  Look deeper.

Comment: Are you sure that you have included jQuery?

Comment: @Charlie Rudenstål: then `$ is not defined` would be thrown

Comment: If you want even `img`s with empty `src=""`, you could `$('#lightboxImage[src]')`.

Comment: @zerkms You are right of course. Interesting that entering `$` directly into the Chrome Console returns `function () { [native code] }` as long as you have not overrided `$` on the page in question. It returns null and doesn't seem to contain anything in particular.

Comment: @Malvolio - You are of course [correct](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGwe/).

Comment: Yes...after a bit more prodding around, I realized that I had a conflict with prototype.js.  Everything seems to work now.  Thanks.

Comment: @JaredFarrish -- I'm imagining you saying that in [Ed McMahon's voice](http://www.maximumdonline.com/tvwavs/mcmahon.wav).

Comment: @Malvolio - While I hate that you linked to a resource that requires Quicktime to load on my machine (whose problem *is that*?), *you are correct sir*. `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with [@Malvolio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713602/error-received-when-testing-for-element-attribute-using-jquery#comment-15539041), your error doesn't *quite* add up. You should not be getting the error you're describing. To wit:

```
<img id="src" class="src" src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"><br/>
<img class="src" src=""><br/>
<img class="src">

console.log($('#nothing').attr('src'));
console.log($('#src').attr('src'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGwe/

Running `onload` gives me:

```
undefined
http://goo.gl/UohAz
```

So your *actual problem* has to do with something else, as Malvolio suggests. I can't necessarily speculate any better than what Malvolio has, except maybe `jQuery()` should be tried in place of `$()`.

---

This is a little bit beside *your* underlying problem, but has to do with what you asked. Instead of doing a test, you could:

```
[src]:not([src=""])
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jSQ3P/3

In your selector and bypass the check. So in other words:

```
$('#lightboxImage[src]:not([src=""])').doStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you attach the code to the click event of the element that needs to raise this code so that it's only called when you need it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickable").click(function() {
        if( $('#lightboxImage').attr('src') !== 'undefined'){
            // do something here 
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `$('#lightboxImage[src]')` will give an element with `src`, even `src=""`. Could be useful, although I don't know in this case if that is desired.

Comment: Well, actually [`[src]:not([src=""]`](http://jsfiddle.net/jSQ3P/) will fix the empty `src` issue.